# The set $B=${$f \in C(D): f(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n z^n$ , with $(a_n) \in l^1(\mathbb{N})$} is "spectrally invariant"

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $D=${$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leq 1$}

$C(D)=${$f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}: f$ is continuous}

Im trying to prove that the set $B=${$f \in C(D): f(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n z^n$ , with $(a_n) \in l^1(\mathbb{N})$} is "spectrally invariant", that is, if $f \in B$ and $f(z) \neq 0  \ \  \forall z \in D $, then $1/f \in B$.

I know that $1/f$ is analytical in $D$, but I dont know how to use this to estimate the coeficients of the power series of $1/f$...

Any hints?

Comment: This follows from (or is a special case of) [Wiener's 1/f theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93L%C3%A9vy_theorem). The additional assumption here is that $f$ extends to a holomorphic function, which is also nonvanishing. Perhaps this assumption makes the proof easier than of the full theorem (which was a 100-page paper in Annals of Math.), but I don't see how.

Comment: Do you know anything about Banach algebras?

Comment: @Desire These days the $1/f$ theorem is a very simple application of basic results about Banach algebras. Details tomorrow if nobody beats me to it...

Comment: Yes, I know. Actually, this question was proposed in a Banach Algebra course Im doying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP says he or she is studying Banach algebras, just a few hints.

(Readers unfamilar with Banach algebras should read the relevant chapter in Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis*. You'll be glad you did! It's lovely stuff, and the present exercise shows that it's very powerful. I mean how the hell does one get information about the Fourier coefficients of $1/f$ "directly"? That 100 pages of Wiener mentioned in a comment above is now just a bit of elegant algebra. The only thing in the chapter that seems somewhat "hard" to me is the proof of the Spectral Radius Formula; you can skip that for our purposes here.)

First show that $B$ is a Banach algebra with the norm $$\|f\|=\sum_n|a_n|\quad(f=\sum_na_nz^n).$$The least trivial part is showing that $\|fg\|\le\|f\|\,\|g\|$, which is not hard.

Now suppose $\phi$ is a complex homomorphism of $B$. (In this context that entails that $\phi$ is non-trivial: $\phi(1)=1$.) Let $\alpha = \phi(z)$. Note that $$|\alpha|\le\|z\|=1.$$

Since $\| f-s_n\|\to0$ (where $s_n$ is the $n$-th partial sum), and $\phi$ is bounded, it follows that $$\phi(f)=f(\alpha)\quad(f\in B).$$

And now you're done. If $f\in B$ and $f(z)\ne0$ for every $z$ in the closed disk then $\phi(f)\ne0$ for every complex homomorphism $\phi$, so the result that I've always felt should be the "Fundamental Theorem" of Banach algebra theory shows that there exists $g\in B$ with $fg=1$.